# ¿Que significa el ''this'' cuando estamos trabajando con objetos en javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

Esto es un ejemplo de mi duda, por que ponerle "this" al principio en lugar de solamente ponerle "wheels = 4" o "seats = 1", etc. ¿De que me puede servir esto al momento de programar?

```
var Car = function() {
  this.wheels = 4;
  this.seats = 1;
  this.engines = 1;
};
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

En JavaScript `this` funciona un poco diferente que en la mayoría de lenguajes orientados a objetos.

- Cuando se usa `this` en una función que no es llamada por ningún objeto, equivale al objeto global `window`.

  ```
  function hacerAlgo() {
      console.log(this); // window
  }
  ```
- Cuando hacemos uso de `this` dentro de una función que existe dentro de una `clase` u `objeto`, hace referencia a la `clase` u `objeto` mismo.

  ```
  function Persona() {
      this.edad = 22; // this = Persona
  }

  var Persona = {
      calcAge: function() {
          console.log(this); // this = Persona
      }
  }
  ```

> ¿Por qué ponerle "this" al principio en lugar de solamente ponerle
>   "wheels = 4" o "seats = 1"?

Esto es cuestión de diseño. En JavaScript **se requiere** usar this en clases para denotar que dicha variable **es propiedad** de la clase. Si no utilizas `this`, dicha variable se **almacena en el scope global**.

Comment: " hace referencia a la clase u objeto mismo." es una frase muy confusa. Javascript no trabaja con clases. (Java se diferencia de los lenguajes OOP no sólo en la división que haces - sino en que no hay clases). "una función que existe dentro de una clase" no tiene mucho sentido en Javascript. FIjarse que ninguna de las respuestas a la  [pregunta en SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) habla de "clases".

Comment: El ejemplo parece dar a entender que `Persona` es algo así como una clase y que el binding de `this` queda determinado por la sintaxis (es decir, se resuelve en tiempo de compilación). No es así.

Comment: Evidentemente hago una mención **abstracta** para que el OP entienda la POO en el modelo prototipado. No me expliques a mí, respóndele al OP.

Comment: muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 6):

Corrijanme si me equivoco:

Voy a generalizar en cuanto a la palabra clave `this` ya que es utilizada por varios lenguajes de programación para hacer referencia al "scope" o ambito del elemento que se utiliza.

Imagina que tenemos el siguiente código:

```
class Miclase
{
    private int X;
    public void SetX(int X)
    {
        this.X = X;
    }
}
```

Existen lenguajes de programación cuyo enfoque principal va hacia las variables locales, antes de cualquier otra cosa, me refiero, si en el código de `SetX(X)` se hubiera puesto lo siguiente:

```
X = X;
```

El compilador no sabria que hacer, diciendole *"asignale el valor del parametro X al parametro X"*. Por lo que `this` hace referencia al objeto que siempre podría estar presente durante toda la instancia.

Al hacer `this.X = X` le estoy diciendo al compilador que asigne el valor de mi parametron `X` en la variable privada `X` que existe en mi clase.

Pasa igual con cualquier elemento, al usar la palabra `this` estas definiendo que el elemento al que deseas llamar es que tiene el nivel de prioridad más "bajo" por así llamarlo.

Donde se podría definir los niveles de prioridad como:

```
Variables/Funciones Locales  (Prioridad 1)
Variables/Funciones Globales (Prioridad 0)
```

Pasa igual con las funciones, imagina que en el Sistema existe una función llamada `Restar()` y tienes un elemento definido con el mismo nombre dentro de una clase o cualquier otro objeto:

```
funcion Restar()  
{
    // Implementacion ...
}
```

Por defecto en cualquier lenguaje de programación, este elemento, pertenece a una clase o un objeto de mayor categoría, por lo que si llamamos desde la misma instancia a `Restar()`, la función del Sistema tendrá mas importancia que la que has definido.

```
funcion Main()
{
    Restar(); // Llama a la función del Sistema.
    this.Restar(); 
    // ^ Llama a tu definición siempre que se encuentre dentro de la misma clase
}
```

En último lugar, la palabra clave `this` funciona como "puntero" *(Si así se le puede llamar)* a la instancia actual del objeto, por lo que todo lo anterior mencionado, puede funcionar.

[this : MDN (ingles)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this):

Comment: muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Como otras respuestas dicen, la palabra clave (keyword) `this` se usa en varios lenguajes. Típicamente en lenguajes orientados a objeto con clases (C++ y Java en particular). En estos lenguajes, `this` es una referencia a "este objeto", y sirve para especificar a qué scope nos estamos refiriendo al usar el nombre de una variable (o campo o propiedad). En Javascript es parecido, pero un poco más variado y complicado.

En primera aproximación: `this` estará dentro de una función que forma parte de un objeto; cuando invocamos la función usando este objeto, entonces `this` referenciará a ese objeto. Ejemplo:

```
var persona = {
     edad : 25,
     esMayor : function() {
         console.log("evaluando esMayor() , this=" + this + " edad=" + this.edad);
         return this.edad >= 18;
     }
}

console.log(persona.esMayor());
persona.edad = 17;
console.log(persona.esMayor());
```

Si lo anterior resulta claro, hay que notar un par de cosas (sobre todo para los que venimos de OOP con clases). Primero: notar que no hemos declarado nada que se parezca a una clase "persona", sino un objeto; contra las apariencias, no podemos (al menos no fácilmente) crear varias instancias de esta "persona".
Segundo: podríamos preguntarnos "¿Realmente la referencia `this` es resuelta en tiempo de ejecución? ¿de hecho, aquí, `this` siempre va a corresponder a `persona`, no ?" No, no necesariamente. Ejemplo:

```
var perro = { edad : 10, esViejo : persona.esMayor } ;
console.log("perro:" + perro.esViejo());
```

(Esto es importante para aclarar que lo que importa es el objeto que se usa para *invocar* la función, no el objeto donde "está declarada" la función.)

Ahora bien, hay otro escenario levemente distinto, especial e importante (de hecho, corresponde al ejemplo de la pregunta). Hay en Javascript un tipo muy particular de funciones, los *[constructores](https://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/javascript-constructors-prototypes-and-the-new-keyword)* (el lenguaje, lamentablemente, no las diferencia a nivel sintáctico - en principo, cualquier función puede ser usada como constructor - de hecho, no suele ser así - la convención es usar mayúsuculas en el nombre).

```
var Car = function() {  // esto es (casi seguramente) un constructor
  this.wheels = 4;
  this.seats = 1;
};
```

El uso "normal" de un constructor es con la palabra clave `new`, que permite instanciar varios objetos (no basandonos en una "clase", sino en un constructor, el cual define un prototipo)

```
var car1 = new Car();
var car2 = new Car();
```

Lo que ocurre con la invocación de constructor con `new`... importante entenderlo pero lo relevante aquí es el comportamiento de `this`: en este caso, Javascript primero crea un nuevo objeto y luego llama al constructor usando ese objeto. Entonces, `this`, en ese contexto, apunta al nuevo objeto creado.

Finalmente, ¿qué pasa si se usa `this` en un contexto global, (fuera de una función, o en una función que no es llamada como propiedad de un objeto)? En tal caso, `this` apunta al "objeto global" (`window`). Es raro que uno esté interesado en esto.

Para más detalles, pregunta similar [en SO (inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: muchas gracias!!