# ¿Cuál es el significado de la asignación de la variable 'var that = this;' en angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

En algunos controladores de Angular he visto la siguiente asignación:

```
angular
    .module('users')
    .controller('usersCtrl', function ($scope, $state) {
        'use strict';
         var that = this;
    ...
}
```

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre usar `that` o usar `this`?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Que significa el ''this'' cuando estamos trabajando con objetos en javascript?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/15011/que-significa-el-this-cuando-estamos-trabajando-con-objetos-en-javascript)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Como enmarcas tu pregunta en el contexto de angular te voy a dar una respuesta diferente para que entiendas para que se usa la notación

```
angular
    .module('users')
    .controller('usersCtrl', function ($scope, $state) {
        'use strict';
         var that = this;
         ...
    });
```

Para JavaScript tiene otro significado que puedes encontrar [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/15013/2224)

En angular en la versión [1.1.5](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#115-triangle-squarification-2013-05-22) se introdujo lo que se conoce notación *controllerAs* con la siguiente sintáxis

```
<div ng-controller="<NombreController> as <propiedad>">
```

Hasta ese momento se usaba la siguiente notación

```
angular
    .module('users')
    .controller('usersCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.propiedad = 'valor';
    });
```

y en la vista

```
<div ng-controller="usersCtrl">
    {{propiedad}}
</div>
```

Debido a que el `$scope` es la *fuente de la verdad* esto te permite manipular la vista desde el código JavaScript lo cual es una de las características mas notables del framework.

Esto trae aparejado un problema conocido como el *dot notation*, debido a que los `$scopes` usan un sistema de herencia internamente. Este [artículo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs) (en inglés) recoge dicho problema en detalle

Como podrás leer en el citado artículo la solución es nunca manipular directamente el `$scope` sino una propiedad de este. La notación `controllerAs` resuelve dicho problema por ti ya que crea una propiedad directamente en el `$scope` que puede ser manipulada con la palabra clave `this`.

En el siguiente ejemplo estoy usando `this` y este no tiene ningún efecto en la vista

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('EstandardController', function($scope, $timeout) {
    var that = this;

    that.propiedad = 'valor';

    that.objeto = {
      propiedad: 'valor'
    };

    console.log($scope);

    $timeout(function() {
      console.log($scope);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="EstandardController">
  Manipular this desde la notación estandard no tiene efecto
  <hr>Valor de propiedad: {{propiedad}}
  <hr>Valor de objeto.propiedad: {{objecto.propiedad}}
</div>
```

Si revisas el `$scope` en la consola puedes comprobar que este no ha sido modificado en lo absoluto.

Esto te prueba sin lugar a dudas que para usar `this` en un controller de angular **debes** estar usando obligatoriamente la notación `controllerAs` (de lo contrario no tendría sentido).

Aquí esta el mismo ejemplo pero usando `controllerAs`

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('AsController', function($scope, $timeout) {
    var that = this;

    that.propiedad = 'valor';

    that.objeto = {
      propiedad: 'valor'
    };

    console.log($scope);

    $timeout(function() {
      console.log($scope.foo);
    });

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="AsController as foo">
  Manipular this desde controller as si modifica los valores
  <hr>Valor de propiedad: {{foo.propiedad}}
  <hr>Valor de objeto.propiedad: {{foo.objeto.propiedad}}
</div>
```

No solo funciona sino que puedes ver que luego que el controller se ha ejecutado hay una nueva propiedad `foo` que tiene todo lo que le pusiste a `this`.

¿Como se relaciona el nombre `that` con la propiedad `foo`?

Es una cuestión de consistencia. Si en lugar de `foo` hubiera usado `that` la vista quedaría de esta forma

```
<hr>Valor de propiedad: {{that.propiedad}}
<hr>Valor de objeto.propiedad: {{that.objeto.propiedad}}
```

Lo cual es exactamente lo que tienes en tu controller por lo que no tendrías que estar adivinando quien pertenece a tu controller y quien pertenece a un controller padre.

Para el código JavaScript no hace ninguna diferencia que nombre le pongas, lo importante es que guardes el valor de `this` en una variable para no perder su referencia en eventos y métodos y que **trates** que esta sea consistente con el valor de la propiedad que pusiste en el `$scope` para que sea más legible.

[Aquí](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y032) hay una guía que te da referencias de buenas prácticas para dichas notaciones. Usualmente se usa `var vm = this;`, que equivale a `ViewModel` ya que angular es un MVVM.

Aquí hay otro articulo que también habla sobre `this` y `controllerAs`

[$scope vs. this en angularjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/11323/scope-vs-this-en-angularjs)

Nota: En angular es imposible declarar un controller dentro de otro gracias a su diseño modularizado por lo que no hay riesgo que el valor de `this` de un controller se mezcle con otro. En la vista es otro tema pero cada controller tiene su `$scope` independiente.

**Update**

Existe otro caso donde se puede usar `this` en un controller y es en una directiva donde se quiera aplicar herencia ya que los controllers de las directivas padre pueden ser obtenidos si se usa la configuración `require`, por ejemplo

```
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
        // controller => ngModel
    }
}
```

Esta configuración se puede usar, por ejemplo, para añadir validadores customizados a [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) y es usado internamente por directivas como [`ng-required`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRequired) y [`ng-pattern`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern).

Puedes usar una función pre-link o post-link para acceder al controller solicitado y mandar a ejecutar alguna función de este. Para que dichas funciones estén disponibles en las directivas hijas debes agregar propiedades a la función del controller y esto se logra usando `this`

Ejemplo

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('padre', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: true,
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.contador = 0;
       
        // Esta función estará disponible
        this.incrementar = function() {
          $scope.contador++;
        }
      }
    };
  })
  .directive('hijo', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      require: '^padre',
      template: '<button type="button" ng-click="invocar()">Incrementar</button>',
      link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, controller) {
        $scope.invocar = function() {
          // Esta función es la misma que la referenciada en la directiva anterior
          controller.incrementar();
        };
      }
    };
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <padre>
    Contador: {{contador}}
    <br>
    <br>
    <hijo>
    </hijo>
  </padre>
</div>
```

Si te fijas en el ejemplo el botón se crea dentro de la directiva `hijo` sin embargo es posible acceder al controller de la directiva `padre` y manipular propiedades de este.

Es importante que entiendas que esto no tiene nada que ver con la notación `controllerAs` ya que desde el momento que usas `require` el controller de la directiva padre (cualquiera que sea su configuración) estará disponible en el **cuarto** parámetro de las funciones pre y post link de todas las directivas hijas **que lo soliciten**

Answer (score 3):

`this` es un concepto confuso en JavaScript que depende del contexto significa una cosa u otra.

Tanto en Angular como en otros framework se suele usar esa técnica de `that` para poder acceder dentro de otros contextos al `this` de nivel superior y no crear conflictos. Siendo los contextos de `this` los siguientes:

**Contexto global**

En el contexto de ejecución global (fuera de cualquier función), this se refiere al objeto global, ya sea en modo estricto o no.

```js
console.log(this.document === document); // true
```

```
// En los navegadores web, el objeto window también es un objeto global:
```

```js
console.log(this === window); // true

this.a = 37;
console.log(window.a); // 37
```

**Contexto de la función**

Dentro de una función, el valor de `this` depende de cómo la función es llamada.

```js
function f1(){
  return this;
}

console.log(f1() === window); // objeto global
```

En este caso, el valor de `this` no está establecido por la llamada. Dado que el código no está en modo estricto, el valor de this debe ser siempre un objeto por lo que por defecto es el objeto global.

```js
function f2(){
  "use strict"; // consultar modo estricto
  return this;
}

console.log(f2() === undefined);
```

**Contexto del objeto**

Cuando una función es llamada como un método de un objeto, `this` cambia por al objeto (como en otros lenguajes la palabra `self`)

```js
var myApp = {
  name : 'Megan',
  lastName : 'Fox',
  completeName (){
    return this.name + ' ' + this.lastName
  }
};

console.log(myApp.completeName());
```

Comment: Para JavaScript lo que pones es cierto, para angular no lo es. En angular se usa `this` en los controladores para acceder al mismo objeto del controller y realmente no importa cual es el nombre de la variable que le asignes, puede ser `vm`, `self`, `that` o `foo`. Los controllers de angular son modularizados por ende no hay conflictos de ámbitos como pones en tu respuesta.