# Usar controlador sin $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

```js
angular.module('App')
    .config(function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('solicitud', {
                url: 'solicitud',
                controller: 'SolCtrl as sol',
                templateUrl: '/scripts/app/estados/solicitud/solicitud.html'
            })
    });


angular.module('App').controller('SolCtrl', solCtrl);

function solCtrl($http, $scope) {

    var solicitud = this;
    solicitud.name = 'Solicitud //ABANCA';

    function respuestaCtrl() {
        this.solicitud = function () {
            alert('funciona');

        }
    }


    $scope.datos = {};
    $scope.datos.cantidad = "";
    $scope.datos.cuota = "";
    $scope.datos.plazos = "";
    $scope.datos.tipo = "";

    $scope.formulario = {}
    $scope.formulario.cantidad = 0;
    $scope.formulario.plazos = 0;
    $scope.formulario.tipo = "hipotecario";

    var logresultado = function (respuesta) {
        $scope.datos.cantidad = $scope.cantidad;
        $scope.datos.cuota = $scope.cuota;
        $scope.datos.plazos = $scope.plazos
        $scope.datos.tipo = $scope.tipoCredito;
    };

    $scope.selected = 'Crédito hipotecario';
    $scope.radioOptions = [
       { name: 'Crédito hipotecario', value: 'hipotecario' },

       { name: 'Crédito personal', value: 'personal' },
    ];

    $scope.showMe = false;

    $scope.myForm = function () {

        var baseURL = 'http://localhost:58498/api/cuota?';
        var cantidad = 'cantidad=' + $scope.formulario.cantidad;
        var plazos = '&plazos=' + $scope.formulario.plazos;
        var tipo = '&tipo=' + $scope.formulario.tipo;

        $scope.get(baseURL + cantidad + plazos + tipo).success(function (respuesta) {

            console.log(respuesta)
            logresultado(respuesta);

            console.log('entra aqui')
            $scope.showMe = !$scope.showMe;

        })

    }


   

};
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
    <form action="http://localhost:58498/api/Cuota" class="form-horizontal"
          method="get" role="form" id="formulario-cuotas">
        
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="Cuotas">¿Cuánto quieres pedir?</label>
            <input class="form-control" data-val="true"
                   data-val-cuotas="El campo de las Cuotas está vacío. No es válido"
                   data-val-required="El campo Cuotas es obligatorio." id="Cuotas"
                   name="cantidad" type="number" value=""
                   ng-model="formulario.cantidad">
            <span class="field-validation-valid text--danger"
                  data-valmsg-for="Cuotas" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <p>
            "Con el préstamo 24h puedes pedir a partir <br>
            de 500€, pero para cantidades de hasta 3000€ <br>
            tiene que ser en la "<a href="/es/tarjetas/tarjetas-credito/tarjeta-visa-clip" target="_blank">
                modalidad de
                tarjeta <br>
            </a>
            ".Por eso este simulador empieza en 3000€ que <br>
            es lo mínimo que puedes pedir en la modalidad <br>
            de préstamo. Ten en cuenta que no puedes <br>
            solicitar más de lo que cuesta lo que vayas <br>
            financiar."
        </p>


        <br>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Plazo" class="control-label">¿Cuándo deseas devolverlo?</label>
            <input class="form-control" data-val="true"
                   data-val-cuotas="El campo de los plazos está vacío. No es válido"
                   data-val-required="El campo Plazos es obligatorio." id="Plazos"
                   name="plazos" type="text" value=""
                   ng-model="formulario.plazos">
            <span class="field-validation-valid text--danger"
                  data-valmsg-for="Plazos" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <p>
            "Puedes devolverlo en un plazo maximo de 96 meses,<br>
            osea, 8 años"
        </p>



        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label" ng-repeat="option in radioOptions">
                <input type="radio" ng-model="formulario.tipo" value="{{option.value}}" ng-required="!formulario.tipo" ng-value="true">
                {{option.name}}

                <br>
            </label>

        </div>


        <br>
        <br>


    </form>

    <div>
        <div>
            <button ng-click="myForm()">
                NG-ENVIAR
              
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="col-md-6">
    <div ng-show="showMe">

        <div>

            <respuesta datos="contenedor"></respuesta>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Buenos días. Me mandaron usar un código que ya tengo pero sin usar el **$scope** .
Estoy con **Angularjs** . Estuve mirando por Internet pero sinceramente no me entero muy bien.

Aquí el código que tengo con el **$scope**:

```
angular.module('formApp').controller('formAppCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    var vm = this;

    $scope.contenedor = {};
    $scope.contenedor.cantidad = "";
    $scope.contenedor.cuota = "";
    $scope.contenedor.plazos = "";
    $scope.contenedor.tipo ="";

    $scope.formulario = {}
    $scope.formulario.cantidad = 0;
    $scope.formulario.plazos = 0;
    $scope.formulario.tipo = "hipotecario";

    var logresultado = function (respuesta) {
        $scope.contenedor.cantidad = respuesta.cantidad;
        $scope.contenedor.cuota = respuesta.cuota;
        $scope.contenedor.plazos = respuesta.plazos
        $scope.contenedor.tipo = respuesta.tipoCredito;
    };

    $scope.selected = 'Crédito hipotecario';
    $scope.radioOptions = [
       { name: 'Crédito hipotecario', value: 'hipotecario' },

       { name: 'Crédito personal', value: 'personal' },
    ];

    $scope.showMe = false;


    $scope.myForm = function () {

        var baseURL = 'http://localhost:58498/api/cuota?';
        var cantidad = 'cantidad=' + $scope.formulario.cantidad;
        var plazos = '&plazos=' + $scope.formulario.plazos;
        var tipo = '&tipo=' + $scope.formulario.tipo;

        $http.get(baseURL+cantidad+plazos+tipo).success(function (respuesta) {

            console.log(respuesta)
            logresultado(respuesta);

        console.log('entra aqui')
        $scope.showMe = !$scope.showMe;

        })

    }
});
```

Y aquí el **js** donde lo tengo que implantar pero sin el **$scope**:

```
    angular.module('App')
        .config(function ($stateProvider) {
            $stateProvider
                .state('solicitud', {
                    url: 'solicitud',
                    controller: 'SolCtrl as sol',
                    templateUrl: '/scripts/app/estados/solicitud/solicitud.html'
                })
        });


    angular.module('App').controller('SolCtrl', solCtrl);

    function solCtrl($http, $scope) {

        var solicitud = this;
        solicitud.name = 'Solicitud //ABANCA';

        function respuestaCtrl() {
            this.solicitud = function () {
                alert('funciona');

            }
        }
};
```

Gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Tecnicamente nunca dejas de usar `$scope` si usas la notación controllerAs, solo que no lo referencias directamente en tu controller a menos que necesites hacer un `$watch`. En angularjs el `$scope` es siempre la fuente de la verdad para la vista. Lee http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/23169/cu%C3%A1l-es-el-significado-de-la-asignaci%C3%B3n-de-la-variable-var-that-this-en-an/23205#23205 y http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/11323/scope-vs-this-en-angularjs/11362#11362

Comment: Vale, gracias por la informacion1 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te fijas, al inicio del controlador, estás asignando `this` a la variable vm.

Te habrán explicado lo que significa ya `this` así que pasaré a lo práctico.

Por lo que para dejar de usar $scope, tienes que hacer 2 cosas:

1. Quitar la inyección del $scope en la cabecera del controlador (dejando sólo $http como dependencia).
2. Sustituir `$scope` por `vm`.

Además, como mejora, te planteo el siguiente controlador:

```
angular.module('formApp').controller('formAppCtrl', function ($http) {

var vm = this;

vm.contenedor = {};
vm.formulario = {
  cantidad: 0,
  plazos: 0,
  tipo: "hipotecario"
};

var logresultado = function (respuesta) {
  vm.contenedor = respuesta;
};

vm.selected = 'Crédito hipotecario';
vm.radioOptions = [
   { name: 'Crédito hipotecario', value: 'hipotecario' },
   { name: 'Crédito personal', value: 'personal' },
];
vm.showMe = false;

vm.myForm = function () {

  var baseURL = 'http://localhost:58498/api/cuota?';
  var cantidad = 'cantidad=' + vm.formulario.cantidad;
  var plazos = '&plazos=' + vm.formulario.plazos;
  var tipo = '&tipo=' + vm.formulario.tipo;

  $http.get(baseURL+cantidad+plazos+tipo).success(function (respuesta) {
    console.log(respuesta)
    logresultado(respuesta);
    console.log('entra aqui')
    vm.showMe = !vm.showMe;
  })

}
```

});

EDITO: acabo de encontrar una respuesta muy completa aquí https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/11362/23093

Comment: Ya me funciona, muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ponerlo en un fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/

Todos los  `$scope.variable` en el controlador deberían ser `vm.variable`. En el html como has puesto `controller: 'SolCtrl as sol',` en vez de utilizar `variable` tendrías que utilizar `sol.variable`. Prueba a ver y me cuentas:

Ejemplo:

```
angular.module('formApp').controller('formAppCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

  var vm = this;

  $scope.contenedor = {};
  $scope.contenedor.cantidad = "";
  $scope.contenedor.cuota = "";
  $scope.contenedor.plazos = "";
  $scope.contenedor.tipo ="";
  // ...
```

Deberia ser:
    angular.module('formApp').controller('formAppCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

```
  var vm = this;

  vm.contenedor = {};
  vm.contenedor.cantidad = "";
  vm.contenedor.cuota = "";
  vm.contenedor.plazos = "";
  vm.contenedor.tipo ="";
  // ...
```

Y en el html por ejemplo:

`{{sol.cantidad}} // asignandole algo claro si no te va a salir vacio`

Comment: Vale, aqui te dejo el fiddle. Voy a probar si funciona como me has puesto ahora y te comento. Graciaas!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Para dejar de usar el `$scope` sólo necesitas asociar todo lo que ahora estás enganchando al `$scope` al propio controlador.

Esto se puede hacer simplemente con `this.miDato = 'blabla..'`, pero como el controlador también suele contener funciones, y cada una de ellas tiene un contexto propio (un `this` distinto), lo que se suele hacer es poner `var vm = this` al principio del todo del controlador, y usar `vm` en todos los sitios en los que ahora usas `$scope`.

Te dejo aquí un fiddle en el que puedes verlo:

https://jsfiddle.net/9jou4hdm/